# Model View Controller Store - Should I create more than one store object in this situation?

Tags: ios, objective-c, model-view-controller

I'm still not used to the MVCS design pattern. I read in a book that if I was planning to create an app that gets information from an external source, it's better to use MVCS instead of MVC.

I'm currently working on an ios app that gets information from multiple external sources. For example, I'll be fetching info about the weather from a web service, driving directions/time probably from Google, and data from our database via a web service as well.

My question is, do I need to create more than one store object in this situation? Like create a store object for each of the external sources? Or do I just create one for all of them?

Answer (score 2):

I think it really depends on your design approach as you can have dozens of different design approaches which all respect the MVC principles and that therefore are all correct.

Personally I would suggest to try to decompose the problem as much as you can in smaller problems, in order to get the most from the flexibility that a objected oriented environment gives you.

In this case, for instance, you could think about having an abstract store class in which you implement the common functionalities you need to have and then subclassing it for each different web service you need to use and implementing the other functionalities related to that specific service. It's just an idea! I hope this helps.